# History to Maintain People how viewed the SharePoint items

Tags: web-services

I have SharePoint list with items (item 1,item 2,Item 3 or 3 rows), I want to maintain the history or list of people for each item who viewed it.  Can any one help me how can I maintain the history for viewing the items in the new SharePoint list?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using MOSS (2007) or SP 2010 you can setup an Information Management Policy. This allows you to audit various events, including: "Opening or downloading documents, viewing items in lists, or viewing item properties"

You can set auditing at various levels, including: content types, the web application, etc.

More info here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262490.aspx and http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc824909(office.12).aspx

Comment: Hi Howard,  Thanks for your response.I configured the Audit settings and then able to view the report ,But I want to save it in SharePoint list,I request you to tell me how can i save it in SharePoint list

Comment: If you want to do this, take a look at the SPAudit class. You could use that to export the audit entries to another list.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the the Site Collection Audit Settings within the Site Collection Administration section of site settings to track views as well.  You can track the following information:

Documents and Items

- Opening or downloading documents, viewing items in lists, or viewing 
  item properties
- Editing items
- Checking out or checking in items
- Moving or copying items to another location in the site
- Deleting or restoring items

Lists, Libraries, and Sites

- Editing content types and columns
- Searching site content
- Editing users and permissions